# TS check if functions have same signature during runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a method that can receive multiple types of functions. I have a specific function `constant` in my application, and I want to prohibit any functions from being passed whose signature matches it - without modifying the method parameter type.

I attempt to do this using `instanceof`

```
const constant = (number) => number

class Context {
    execute(fn: (...args?: any) => any) {
        if (fn instanceof constant)
            return false
    }
}
```

but find that the `instanceof` operation is apparently not supported between functions.

What techniques are available to check during runtime if a function has the same signature as another function, in TypeScript?

Note that "in TypeScript" does not mean I require a solution that is only possible in TypeScript. Vanilla JavaScript approaches are acceptable too, if there is no way for TS to make it nicer.

Comment: You can't do that, the typing is striped at compile time.

Comment: There's no way to do this. There's no such thing as a function signature in JS and even the arity (`Function.prototype.length`) is not automatically checked or respected.

Answer (score 0):

Well you must understand that when you talk about runtime you already omit Typescript. So as an example you can check the pattern of the function as string. But its quite **Dirty way**. I would question what are you trying to achieve because if you use TS then it may be not the best idea to run dynamic functions. But anyways, here is how your resulted js should look like.

```js
const constant = (number) => number

class Context {
    execute(fn) {        
         if (typeof fn === 'function' && /\(number\) => /.test(fn.toString())) {
           console.log('Function has same pattern as constant');
         }
    }
}


const inst = new Context();
inst.execute(constant);
```

Here is TS version

```
const constant = (number: number) => number

class Context {
    execute(fn: (args?: any) => any): void {
        if (typeof fn === 'function' && /\(number\) => /.test(fn.toString())) {
           console.log('Function has same pattern as constant');
         }
    }
}

const inst = new Context();
inst.execute(constant); // true
inst.execute((notNumber: number) => notNumber); // not true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that check at runtime because typings are only available at compile time. However you can add a constraint with a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) so that any functions of type `const constant: (number: number) => number` are rejected using the type `never`.

```
const constant = (number: number) => number;

type ForbiddenSignature = typeof constant;
//   ^? type ForbiddenSignature = (number: number) => number

class Context {
  execute<T>(fn: T extends ForbiddenSignature ? never : T) {
    // implementaiton
  }
}

const context = new Context();
context.execute(constant);
//              ~~~~~~~~ Argument of type '(number: number) => number'
//                       is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
context.execute((x: string) => {}); // works
context.execute((x: number) => {}); // works
context.execute(() => {}); //works
context.execute((x: number) => 0); // error
//              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Argument of type '(x: number) => number'
//                               is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKlQIZlgXhgCjAVwLYCMBTAJwC4YcCSBKGVAPgryOIG4BYAKC6gE8AHQjABiIYvgCWAEymEwAZQkBzMIijZiQ9H0EgAZnHDRkUDpwD05mNYB6Afhg6ho8dNkLlq9ZrqZKLcn8aOkYg4i4uYAAbRAgIGABhcChCAA9YAG8uazTCYGwUgB4AFXoMPTByYpg0lLApeJdJGTlFFTUNIQcwQgA3Ehgq2izOa2tLGAlcfijCXDkkCShwbJgAXy4N7k54aEMUWt8egHdE5NqMajN4FPSAOlz8lIxdpBQrrgmx75%20YAD8AYCATAAILEJR4BYwfSOARCADkWGYJECyOItAYTCoxHhnysvwJhMm8TAIFgsQgnkQ%20FmjhAMH4iGIiHmKWI0IMThg8J6-Rxd0i53ujwKhAwGFS5GgxAkYCUGMYGTWVxgE2OYgA1hBBQdhak8qLxZKsSwFTAlSq1ZrtTshVAHvqnmLLiFzcrWKrzOriFqdbd7SLnhLUdizQAGS1WEjEMR4ok-IGJpN-UHgyEoDmwwTc4Mm4KYsK4iz4%20OlwkSElkmAUqk0oTLBlMlmENmZrk8vokeECzhAA)

Comment: In my case, I can't constrain the method parameter type because, due to the nature of the domain I'm modeling, outsider consumers should be allowed to pass undesired functions to this method, with the method simply preventing runtime failures internally. Being allowed to pass any relevant function on the outside, even if it is prohibited internally, is a feature of the model I'm building.